# Postgres select from table and spread evenly

Tags: postgresql

I have a 2 tables. First table contains information of the object, second table contains related objects. Second table objects have 4 types( lets call em A,B,C,D).

I need a query that does something like this

```
    |table1 object id | A |value for A|B  |  value for B| C | value for C|D  | vlaue for D|
    |     1           | 12| cat       | 13| dog         | 2 | house      | 43| car        |
    |     1           | 5 | lion      |   |             |   |            |   |            |
```

The column "table1 object id" in real table is multiple columns of data from table 1(for single object its all the same, just repeated on multiple rows because of table 2).

Where 2nd table is in form

```
|type|value|table 1 object id| id |
|A   |cat  |      1          |  12|
|B   |dog  |      1          |  13|
|C   |house|      1          |  2 |
|D   |car  |      1          | 43 |
|A   |lion |      1          | 5  |
```

I hope this is clear enough of the thing i want.

I have tryed using AND and OR and JOIN. This does not seem like something that can be done with crosstab.

EDIT
Table 2

```
|type|value|table 1 object id| id |
 |A   |cat  |      1          |  12|
 |B   |dog  |      1          |  13|
 |C   |house|      1          |  2 |
 |D   |car  |      1          | 43 |
 |A   |lion |      1          | 5  |
 |C   |wolf |      2          |  6 |
```

Table 1

```
| id | value1 | value 2|value 3|
|  1 | hello  | test   | hmmm  |
|  2 | bye    | test2  | hmm2  |
```

Result

```
|value1| value2| value3| A| value| B |value| C|value  | D | value|
|hello | test  | hmmm  |12| cat  | 13| dog |2 | house | 23| car  |
|hello | test  | hmmm  |5 | lion |   |     |  |       |   |      |
|bye   | test2 | hmm2  |  |      |   |     |6 | wolf  |   |      |
```

I hope this explains bit bettter of what I want to achieve.

Comment: join and crosstab seems suitable here - show your query that does not work?..

Comment: Not enough information, and it's not clear from the example - how many rows should the query return ? Why it does return 'cat dog house car' but not 'lion dog house car' ?

Comment: @Eugene it needs to return all. Just if we have 2 elements of type A then 2 rows needs to be returned. Basically it needs to return everything connected to object from table 1 in a compact way.

Comment: @VaoTsun i havent been able to create a query that even remotely gives what i need.